# Chi-square test alternatives to test for shift in distributions

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I would like to test the hypothesis that the distribution of windspeeds of Atlantic hurricanes in more recent years (1967 - 2016) has shifted to higher values when compared to earlier years (1900 - 1949).

For that I condition the data for each distribution on year and windspeed (as I only include windspeeds greater or equal to category 1). The R code to arrive a the data for the distributions, plot a visual representation, and to carry out a chi-square test is the following:

```
library(HURDAT)
library(lubridate)

HURDAT2 <- get_hurdat(basin = "AL")

obs_Cat1 <- cbind(HURDAT2$Wind[year(HURDAT2$DateTime) %in% seq(1900,1949) & HURDAT2$Wind >= 64], 
                  HURDAT2$Wind[year(HURDAT2$DateTime) %in% seq(1967,2016) & HURDAT2$Wind >= 64])

plot(density(obs_Cat1[, 1], na.rm = 1), ylim = c(0, 0.04), col = "blue", main = "", xlab = "Windspeed", ylab = "Density")
lines(density(obs_Cat1[, 2], na.rm = 1))
legend("topright", lty = 1, lwd = 1, legend = c("1900 - 1949", "1967 - 2016"), col = c("blue", "black"))

chisq.test(na.omit(obs_Cat1))
```

No I am wondering if the chi-square test is a good choice for such data and resembles a good test for the hypothesis? As far as I understand it is used to check if two distributions are from the same population and hence may not be used to check if a distribution shifts to higher values compared to another distribution. Primarily I am interested if the more recent distribution shifted to higher values but in a second step would also like to look for evidence if the distribution itself changed significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chi-square test of association you are using treats windspeed as a nominal variable.  That is it counts the number of observations that are 65, are 70, are 75, etc.  It treats these as different categories, but doesn't know that e.g. 75 is greater 70 which is greater than 65.  So, this is probably not the approach you want.

The following code in R sets up your data and then shows you the tables that the chi-square test is working on.

```
if(!require(HURDAT)){install.packages("HURDAT")}
if(!require(lubridate)){install.packages("lubridate")}

library(HURDAT)
library(lubridate)

HURDAT2 <- get_hurdat(basin = "AL")

obs_Cat1 <- cbind(HURDAT2$Wind[year(HURDAT2$DateTime) %in% seq(1900,1949) & HURDAT2$Wind >= 64], 
              HURDAT2$Wind[year(HURDAT2$DateTime) %in% seq(1967,2016) & HURDAT2$Wind >= 64])

Tnew = table(obs_Cat1[,1], useNA="ifany")
Told = table(obs_Cat1[,2], useNA="ifany")
Tnew
Told
sum(Told)-338
sum(Tnew)

   ### Tnew

   ### 65  70  75  80  85  90  95 100 105 110 115 120 125 130 135 140 145 150 160 
   ### 667 848 583 556 535 412 325 270 350 151 124 102  80  46  22  18   7   4   3 

   ### Told

   ###  65   70   75   80   85   90   95  100  105  110  115  120  125  130  135  140  145  150  155  160  165 <NA> 
   ### 1065  647  583  450  334  396  225  230  136  155  153  120   92   59   28   39   23   18    9    2    1  338 

   ###  sum(Told)-338
   ###  4765

   ### sum(Tnew)
   ### 5103
```

Instead, you probably want to use a method to compare the distributions that treats the wind speed as a numeric variable, or at least an ordinal one.

To compare the distributions per se, you might use the two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test. There are two points of caution here, though.  First, with 5000 observations in each group, you are likely to get a significant p-value, even for minor differences in the distributions.  Second, while this test tests for a difference in the distributions, it doesn’t answer your question about if the values for one are larger than the other.  I believe the D statistic in the output is an effect size which ranges from 0 to 1. So, if so, the effect size is quite small.

```
ks.test(obs_Cat1[,1], obs_Cat1[,2])

   ### Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
   ### D = 0.092797, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Now comes the difficult part, which is that you need to decide what kind of difference is the distributions would be meaningful.   Would it matter to you if the mean values were different between the two groups?  The median?   The 90th percentile?

First, let me put the data into long format and summarize it.

```
if(!require(FSA)){install.packages("FSA")}
if(!require(lattice)){install.packages("lattice")}

Old = HURDAT2$Wind[year(HURDAT2$DateTime) %in% seq(1900,1949) & HURDAT2$Wind >= 64]
New = HURDAT2$Wind[year(HURDAT2$DateTime) %in% seq(1967,2016) & HURDAT2$Wind >= 64]
Group = c(rep('1900-1949', length(Old)), rep('1967-2016', length(New)))
Wind = c(Old, New)
Data = data.frame(Group, Wind)

library(FSA)
Summarize(Wind ~ Group, data=Data)

   ###       Group    n nvalid     mean       sd min Q1 median Q3 max
   ### 1 1900-1949 3761   3761 85.70593 17.46692  65 70     80 95 160
   ### 2 1967-2016 5103   4765 84.42707 19.62567  65 70     80 95 165

library(lattice)
histogram(~ Wind | Group,
          data=Data,
          layout=c(1,2))
```

A common approach is to compare the means of the two groups with a t-test.  But with skewed data like this, I’m not sure looking at the means is very meaningful.  In lieu of an effect size, we can look at the difference in means.  Is a difference in means of 1.3 between these two groups meaningful?

Again, for these tests, because the sample size is large, you are likely to find a significant p-value even for a small difference between the two groups.

```
t.test(Wind ~ Group, data = Data)

   ### Welch Two Sample t-test
   ### t = 3.1778, df = 8402.2, p-value = 0.001489
   ### mean in group 1900-1949 mean in group 1967-2016 
   ###               85.70593                84.42707
```

An alternative approach to see if there is a systematic difference in the values between to the two groups is to use the Mann-Whitney test.  I’m not sure what to recommend for an effect size for Mann-Whitney, so I’ll skip the effect size for now.

```
wilcox.test(Wind ~ Group, data = Data)

    ### Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
    ### W = 9726200, p-value = 8.449e-12
```

If I were investigating the question, I would want to compare various quantiles of the two distributions.  For example, are their medians different?  Are their 95th percentiles different?

Normally, I would recommend quantile regression for this task, but the quantreg package is giving me some trouble with this data.  So, we’ll use permutation tests.

The following uses quantile regression to test a difference in medians.

```
if(!require(quantreg)){install.packages("quantreg")}

library(quantreg)

model.q = rq(Wind ~ Group,
             data = Data,
             tau  = 0.50)

summary(model.q)
```

The following uses a permutation test to compare the 10th percentiles.

```
if(!require(rcompanion)){install.packages("rcompanion")}

library(rcompanion)

groupwisePercentile(Wind ~ Group,
                    data = Data,
                    tau  = 0.10,
                    bca  = FALSE,
                    R    = 1000)

   ###       Group    n tau Percentile
   ### 1 1900-1949 3761 0.1         65
   ### 2 1967-2016 4765 0.1         65


percentileTest(Wind ~ Group,
               data = Data,
               test = "percentile",
               tau  = 0.10,
               r    = 5000)

   ###           p.value
   ### 1 p-value       1
```

And I'll do some of the tedious work.

```
Table of Quantile Results

Quantile  1900-1949  1967-2016  p-value
0.00       65         65        n.s.
0.05       65         65        n.s.
0.10       65         65        n.s.
0.25       70         70        n.s.
0.50       80         80        n.s.
0.75       95         95        n.s.
0.90      110        115        n.s.
0.95      120        125        n.s.
1.00      160        165        n.s.
```

So, what would I conclude?  Well, there is a significant difference between the two distributions (2-sample K.S. test) and there is some systematic difference (Mann-Whitney).  But with the sample size, I wouldn't imbue too much meaning to the p-values.  And the difference in means is 1.3, which seems meaningless for this data.  There is a numeric difference in the 90th, 95th, and 100th percentiles, but each is only 5, which doesn’t seem like much to me for data.  However, there is a suggestive increase in wind speed for the later time period for the 90th percentile and greater.

So, one last test.  If there were some meaning to, say, a wind speed of 110, we might see if there was a difference in the proportion of observations above or equal to this value.

```
library(rcompanion)

percentileTest(Wind ~ Group,
               data = Data,
               test = "proportion",
               threshold  = 110,
               comparison = ">=",
               r    = 5000)

   ###           p.value
   ### 1 p-value   4e-04
```

Comment: Sal, thank you very much for the extensive answer, great work! I tried working with the quantreg package as well and also had my troubles, so in the end, for fitting linear models for different quantiles, I just wrote out some code that will do for this task. Going forward I will go trough the methods in detail. From the above, would it be valid then to do the chi-square test for the count of storms per year agains the periods?

Comment: Because the two time periods have the same number of years, I suppose you could use a chi-square goodness-of-fit test.  `Storms = c(20, 30); chisq.test(Storms, p=c(0.5, 0.5))`, but I feel like a Poisson test would be more appropriate.  I'm not very familiar with this test, but the comparable example might be `poisson.test(c(20,30), c(49,49),1)`.